# Perform UIAlertView before performing segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, segue

When I segue from **View Controller A** to **View Controller B**, How do I load my UIAlertView BEFORE the segue occurs? The UIAlertView seems to just load in the next screen...

I tried implementing the UIAlertView in the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

section, but I wasn't able to get a result.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{


if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"report"])

{
    [self loadingData];

}{

                [self retrieveData];

                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
                Company *currentStore = [arrayOfStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


                ReportsViewController *destinationVC = [segue destinationViewController];
                destinationVC.name = name;
```

self loadingData is my UIAlertView void statement. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is by **reworking your flow** like this: make ViewControllerA a delegate of the UIAlertView you are showing, then use the alertView Delegate call to perform the segue. You can do it like this:

First make a segue **between the 2 ViewControllers** in Storyboard, I call it toViewController2:

[image: segue storyboard]

Now go to your .m file of ViewController 1 make it a UIViewController Delegate:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Create an alertView (with **delegate:self**)in your didSelect method of your tableView:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Loading" message:@"Please wait while loading" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]; // build the alertview
    [alertView show]; // show the alertview
}
```

When the button on the alertView is clicked, the performSegue is called:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toViewController2" sender:nil]; // perform segue after cancelbutton was pressed on alertview
}
```

And finally the performSegue method is called AFTER your alertView:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toViewController2"])
    {
        // Do stuff AFTER the alertview button is pressed
    }
}
```

I'm not a fan of segmented tutorial or explanations so here's it all together:
[image: all together]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It worked. The problem I was facing earlier was that I had the segue from the table view cell to the new view controller

Answer (score 1):

Don't invoke your segue right away. When the user action happens (selecting a row in your table view?) then display your alert view. Set yourself up as the delegate of the alert. When the alert view delegate's `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method is called, make sure the user clicked the correct button, and then invoke your segue in code using the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this -

1. In your method prepareForSegue - First show the alert box, and then perform the segue when the user taps the "done" or "ok" button.
2. Use a delegate - make "self" as the delegate of the alert view, and when the user taps on the alert view, use a delegate method, which is implemented in the view controller class you are in, to call performWithSegue.